# How do you change a global variable with a segmented control in swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, uisegmentedcontrol

I am trying to update a table view with a segmented control. I am doing this by assigning a variable and the global variable will not change when the user selects one of the segmented controls. I want the data displayed so that if the user matches the user who created the report AND the reports matching the segmented control are displayed. Any suggestions?

```
class ReportsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var reportList:[String] = []

var ref: DatabaseReference!

var handle: DatabaseHandle?

var pageStatus = "default"


@IBOutlet weak var reportsTableView: UITableView!

@IBAction func backButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "reportsToHome", sender: self)
}

@IBOutlet weak var segmentControl: UISegmentedControl!

@IBAction func segmentControlPressed(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    switch segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex
    {

    case 0:
        self.pageStatus = "unclaimed";
        self.reportsTableView.reloadData()
        print("0 selected " + self.pageStatus)
        return;
    case 1:
        self.pageStatus = "complete";
        self.reportsTableView.reloadData()
        print("1 selected " + self.pageStatus)
        return;
    case 2:
        self.pageStatus = "cancelled";self.reportsTableView.reloadData()
        print("2 selected " + self.pageStatus)
        return;
    default:
        break;
    }
}


public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return reportList.count

}


public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

    cell.textLabel?.text = reportList[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ref = Database.database().reference()

    handle = ref.child("Reports").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let reports = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
                let firstName = reports["firstName"] as? String
                let lastName = reports["lastName"] as? String
                let user = reports["user"] as? String
                let status = reports["status"] as? String
                let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

                for report in reports{
                    if user == userID{
                        if status == self.pageStatus{
                            self.reportList.append(firstName! + " " + lastName!)
                            self.reportsTableView.reloadData()

                        }
                        else{
                            print("not again")
                            print(self.pageStatus)
                            print(status)
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        print(status ?? "page status" + self.pageStatus);
                        print(user);
                        print(userID)
                    }

                }
            }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
)}
```

Comment: can u add some examples because it is not very clear what you need. Also an image of your application will help if thats possible.

Comment: I would like to display different reports in a table view based on which user created them. If the user selects 'Unclaimed' on a segmented control, it displays all unclaimed reports that they created. I cannot take an image right now, but I will try to get one up today. A report has a name (like 'Report 1'), a user who created it, and a status (unclaimed, claimed, and complete). Users have a user ID randomly assigned by firebase.